# git clone does't work on docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-container

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 machine that runs Docker and docker-compose. On my ubuntu, I've spun up the Ubuntu docker container. From my machine, I can do a `git clone` to pull down a repo that is working well but in the container, I can ping the git server but when I issue the exact same `git clone` command that pauses a few minutes long and throws an error, I mention that error message below,

```
fatal: unable to access '{https://git-server/username/my-repo.git/}' : Failed to connect to {git-server} port 443: Connection timed out
```

Even when I set up ssh on git-server it does not work causing the same kind of error I will mention that also below,

```
ssh: connect to host {git-server} port 22: connection timed out
```

Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to run `git` from inside a container: the image contains an immutable copy of the application source code already.  Usually I'd call `git` from the host and then run `docker build` using the Dockerfile checked into the source tree.  The symptom you describe sounds more like a networking problem than a programming question.

Comment: That’s all true, but also, you should be able to do this. It’s totally possible your network, docker container, git configuration, or your actual call is the problem. Without more information, we really can’t help. Check out the guide to creating a [mre] and at the very least post the actual code that produces the problem.  If you can’t share your production code, start a new repo and try to reproduce this with a dummy build spec.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks, next time I will definitely follow the minimal reproducible example. Now the problem is solved, after a lot of searching, I found a thing on the internet. They say "may be due to ufw rules", so I disabled ufw and tested it, it worked fine, then I edited ufw rules and turned it on.

Comment: Great! Feel free to post and accept that as an answer! Could help others in the same situation.